# Use extension method to access Entity Framework Core shadow property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

To improve readability and provide some level of type safety, I am trying to extract usage of [`EF.Property()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-6.0) into an extension method:

```cs
public static Guid TenantIdLinq(this ITenanted entity)
{
    return EF.Property<Guid>(entity, ITenanted.Column);
}
```

so that I can use it in a global query filter or `.Where`/`.Select` clauses. e.g.

```cs
entity.HasQueryFilter(e => e.TenantIdLinq() == this.tenantService.TenantId);
```

or

```cs
context.Tenant.Select(t => t.TenantIdLinq());
```

Of course, the Entity Framework Core engine doesn't like this because it doesn't know to substitute the body of the extension method in place of the method call:

Error when executing `<snip>`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(s => (Nullable)s
> .TenantIdLinq() == __ef_filter__TenantId_0)'
> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I realise I can probably use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to solve this, but was hoping for an inbuilt or quick and dirty version I could implement myself to avoid pulling in a whole library for this single, narrow use case.

Comment: Please add a tag for the EF version used (ef-core-??).

Comment: If you want to access the column everywhere, maybe you should make it a real column rather than a shadow property...

Comment: Yeah, I ended up adding it as a real property to just the Tenant table (which was only where I was using it anyway) but kept it as a shadow property on entities where I wasn't accessing it.